# How do I change the color around the FAB that's center docked in the custom bottom app bar?

Tags: flutter, dart

So I want to be able to fill in the color around the `FAB` but I'm not sure how. I followed [this](https://medium.com/coding-with-flutter/flutter-bottomappbar-navigation-with-fab-8b962bb55013) article exactly so there's the custom bar.

[image: actual results]
[image: expected results]

Comment: Try to set `backgroundColor` in `Scaffold`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can wrap it in a container or other placeholder widget and set a background color. Don't know if this works for sure. Let me know!
Greetz

edit: just checked my answer, if you implement this (example) code:

```
 bottomNavigationBar: Container( color: Colors.red, 
    child: FABBottomAppBar(
    centerItemText: 'A',
    color: Colors.grey,
    selectedColor: Colors.red,
    notchedShape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),
    onTabSelected: _selectedTab,
    items: [
      FABBottomAppBarItem(iconData: Icons.menu, text: 'This'),
      FABBottomAppBarItem(iconData: Icons.layers, text: 'Is'),
      FABBottomAppBarItem(iconData: Icons.dashboard, text: 'Bottom'),
      FABBottomAppBarItem(iconData: Icons.info, text: 'Bar'),
    ],
  ),
  ),
```

it creates [background color of FAB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUMdw.png)

Comment: A bit of trial and error should give your answer. I think the bottom app bar or both should do the trick

Comment: Why not? It can be wrapped and have styling options... The scaffold is as you said also a option but then your whole page is red...

Comment: Currently not in reach of a computer, when I am I'll post my result

Comment: Seems to be working, see my added picture and code.

Comment: Great, +1 from my side!

Answer (score 1):

Use this as your `Scaffold`

```
Scaffold(
   floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(onPressed: null, child: Icon(Icons.add),),
   floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
   backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
   bottomNavigationBar: Container(
     color: Colors.white,
     child: BottomAppBar(
       color: Colors.purple,
       child: Padding(
         padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 56, vertical: 12),
         child: Row(
           mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
           children: <Widget>[
             Icon(Icons.home, color: Colors.white,),
             Icon(Icons.perm_contact_calendar, color: Colors.white,),
           ],
         ),
       ),
       shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),
     ),
   ),
 );
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can as well remove the background of the CircularNotchedRectangle by adding 'extendBody: true' to the Scaffold widget. NOTE: Make sure you don't wrap the body of the Scaffold with SafeArea widget as this defeats the aim of removing the background.